# I want to add err message if folders are not moved.To explain source and target path err.Also can be included web link for instructions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-modules, electron-builder

Folder is moved with this code but i need to catch err if folders are not moved(from some 
reason if something go bad) to explain source and target path (locations of that folders that are 
not merged-moved)I put alarm but this don't explain nothing.Also i need web link in 
message for instructions(what is needed to do to fix manually) if is possibble to do that?

```
  newcPath = path.join(app.getPath('home'), '/Appdata/Local/Active/newbase')
  newcPathExists = fs.existsSync(newcPath)
  if (!newcPathExists) {
     currentcPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), './extor/base')
      currentcPathExists = fs.existsSync(currentcPath)
      if (currentcPathExists) {
          try {
              fs.renameSync(currentcPath, newcPath)
          } catch (err) {
              alert('Cant move folders')

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: alert is browser API not Node API.

Comment: You are calling alert in your main and this can't be like this.

Comment: i know i wil change to  console.error('Cant move folders:', err)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no electron expert, but it looks like you might need to use [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog)

```js
const { dialog } = require('electron')

const showDialog = () => {
  dialog.showMessageBox({ ...options })
}
```

You could put something like this ^ in your `catch` block

Comment: can i add catch (err) {  if fs.renameSync(newcPath) = false alert('Gateway metadata is not moved to /Appdata/Local/ScPrime/') }

Comment: Why not write a showDialog() function that shows a dialog box/alert with a link? You can put this function in the catch block ... or elsewhere if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
  newcPath = path.join(app.getPath('home'), '/Appdata/Local/Active/newbase')
  newcPathExists = fs.existsSync(newcPath)

  if (!newcPathExists) {
     currentcPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), './extor/base')
      currentcPathExists = fs.existsSync(currentcPath)
      if (currentcPathExists) {
          try {
              fs.renameSync(currentcPath, newcPath)
          } catch (err) {
            dialog.showMessageBox(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), {
              type: "error",
              message: "Cannot File Move " + err.message? err.message | err,
            });
         }
     }
  }
```

As you know, we can't use alert at main process from this is browser API not Node API. This just available at render.

If you wanna show sth to users then you can use this [dialog.showMessageBox](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options)